# insertion to type map in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I dont understand what does that piece of code does

```
static TwoWayHostPair hostpair;
map <TwoWayHostPair, Traffic> mymap;
//here some map element inserted to mymap and hostpair initialized

map <TwoWayHostPair, Traffic>::iterator iter = mymap.begin();
iter = mymap.find(hostpair);
if (iter == mymap.end()) { 
    iter = mymap.insert(make_pair(hostPair, Traffic())).first; //line8
}
```

My question is what happens in line8? I didnt get it. Isnt it supposed to be type `map<...>:iterator` and after this insertion does it stay same type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

std::map::insert return **std::pair< iterator,bool >**, below statement is correct. second bool return value indicates whether the insertion took place

```
iter = mymap.insert(make_pair(hostPair, Traffic())).first; //line8
```

see reference [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert)

Answer (score 1):

As used here,

```
iter = mymap.insert(make_pair(hostPair, Traffic())).first; //line8
```

`mymap.insert` [returns](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/) a `pair<iterator,bool>`.  `first`, then, [accesses](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/) the `iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert(make_pair......
```

`make_pair` is used to insert pair value to a map.You have iterated for all the element in map having hostpair.

**EDIT**
Refer [cplusplus map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) to know more.

Comment: that part is quite obvious, what I asked is answered below by Nate Chandler and billz

Answer (score 0):

```
iter = mymap.find(hostpair);
if (iter == mymap.end()) { 
    iter = mymap.insert(make_pair(hostPair, Traffic())).first; //line8
}
```

The first line *looks* for key `hostPair` in the map, and if it is not found, then it enters the `if` block where it inserts the key along with its value, and `.first` returns the iterator to the inserted item.

---

**Improvement**

But you can make an improvement to this. You could just write this:

```
iter = mymap.insert(make_pair(hostPair, Traffic())).first;
```

which is exactly **equivalent** to your code. No need to use `find` and then `insert`. The result is a *performance* gain.

If the key already exists, the `insert` function will NOT insert any item to the map and `.first` will return you the iterator to the *found* item.  If the key doesn't exist, only then it will insert and `.first` will return you the iterator to the *newly inserted* item.

If you want to know whether the key already existed or not, then you can do this:

```
auto pair = mymap.insert(make_pair(hostPair, Traffic())); //NO .first!
if (pair.second)
{
     //a newly created item is inserted 
     auto iter = pair.first; //iterator to the newly inserted item
}
else
{
    //an item with key `hostPair` already exists in the map
     auto iter = pair.first; //iterator to the found item
}
```

Hope that helps.